# How to identify a bluetooth device?

Tags: bluetooth, kernel-panic, uuid

I am having kernel—task taking up to 1000% of my CPU, starting the fan and making the iMac unresponsive. (Catalina 10.15.7)

In trying to identify the cause I looked in the logs where I have 2 or 3 times per second the message flagged as error :
bluetoothd : ScanManager: device doesn't exist for peer: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
where X is in the range 0-9 A-F.

This looks like a UUID code, but no computer on the network matches.

I assume we are speaking of a bluetooth device invisible, but I don't see anything relevant in bluetooth explorer app.
Not sure that is the cause of the panic, but I would like to identify what device is concerned.

Any idea on how to proceed ?